# How to install Network Adapter Drivers for Atheros AR8161/8165 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.20) Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers, atheros, ethernet

How can I install drivers for 64-bit Atheros AR8161/8165 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.20) for Ubuntu 12.04. I dual boot Windows7/Ubuntu 12.04 drivers work for 64-bit Windows 7.

lspic -nn:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller [8086:0154] (rev 09) 
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge PCI Express Root Port [8086:0151] (rev 09) 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09) 
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04) 
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04) 
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04) 
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04) 
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1e10] (rev c4) 
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1e12] (rev c4) 
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:1e16] (rev c4) 
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04) 
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller [8086:1e59] (rev 04) 
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:1e03] (rev 04) 
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04) 
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:0de9] (rev a1) 
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1091] (rev 08) 
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2200 [8086:0891] (rev c4) 
04:00.0 System peripheral [0880]: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller [197b:2392] (rev 30) 
04:00.2 SD Host controller [0805]: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller [197b:2391] (rev 30) 
04:00.3 System peripheral [0880]: JMicron Technology Corp. MS Host Controller [197b:2393] (rev 30) 
04:00.4 System peripheral [0880]: JMicron Technology Corp. xD Host Controller [197b:2394] (rev 30)
```

sudo lshw -c network

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED      
       description: Ethernet controller 
       product: AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet 
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc. 
       physical id: 0 
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0 
       version: 08 
       width: 64 bits 
       clock: 33MHz 
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list 
       configuration: latency=0 
       resources: memory:d3a00000-d3a3ffff ioport:2000(size=128) 
  *-network 
       description: Wireless interface 
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 2200 
       vendor: Intel Corporation 
       physical id: 0 
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0 
       logical name: wlan0 
       version: c4 
       serial: 9c:4e:36:14:d4:7c 
       width: 64 bits 
       clock: 33MHz 
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless 
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.2.0-23-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn 
       resources: irq:45 memory:d3900000-d3901fff
```

I also tried Manually configuring wired connection. Nether wired or wireless connects

Comment: Run `lspci -nn` in a terminal and give us the result.

Comment: edited orginal question to include more data

Comment: for Lenovo ideaPad. no driver found in component catalog on ubuntu site

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: The ALX driver will be officially added in newer kernels, but in the meantime you can find it here:
[The ALX driver](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/alx)

The original poster didn't put this up so I will.  Apparently there is supposed to be a combined bluetooth/network driver by Atheros, and it needs the alx module. (From someone elses post on Ubuntu 12.04) but there is no alx module.  Still isn't showing up on my Lenovo Ideapad Y480 on kernel 3.5.0-18.

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1091] (rev 08)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3979]
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort->SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 11
Region 0: Memory at d3600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
Region 2: I/O ports at 2000 [size=128]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0+,D1+,D2+,D3hot+,D3cold+)
    Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
Capabilities: [58] Express (v1) Endpoint, MSI 00
    DevCap: MaxPayload 4096 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s unlimited, L1 unlimited
        ExtTag- AttnBtn+ AttnInd+ PwrInd+ RBE+ FLReset-
    DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
        RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
    DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
    LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Latency L0 unlimited, L1 unlimited
        ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot-
    LnkCtl: ASPM L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk+
        ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
    LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
Capabilities: [c0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/16 Maskable+ 64bit+
    Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Masking: 00000000  Pending: 00000000
Capabilities: [d8] MSI-X: Enable- Count=16 Masked-
    Vector table: BAR=0 offset=00002000
    PBA: BAR=0 offset=00003000
Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
    UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
    UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
    UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
    CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
    CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
    AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap+ CGenEn- ChkCap+ ChkEn-
Capabilities: [180 v1] Device Serial Number ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff
```